# docker - Any way to view all preceding Dockerfiles?

Tags: docker, dependencies, dockerfile, dependency-management

For example:

- **python:3.6-stretch** [pulls from](https://github.com/docker-library/python/blob/341c752e5435f4cf4c008fbae67ae4b5b6209a02/3.6/stretch/Dockerfile#L7) **buildpack-deps:stretch**
- which in turn [pulls from](https://github.com/docker-library/buildpack-deps/blob/d7da72aaf3bb93fecf5fcb7c6ff154cb0c55d1d1/stretch/Dockerfile#L1) **buildpack-deps:stretch-scm**
- which in turn...

Thus I am wondering: *is there a way to download/view all preceding Dockerfiles* to understand what is coming from where and how?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[`docker history <IMAGE>`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/history/) will show you the history of an image. Some histories are better than others but you can get a sense of what is being done at each layer on the way. Size 0B usually means metadata added to the image while anything greater than 0B means `ADD`, `COPY`, `RUN`, or other file system related change.

if there an IMAGE ID then you can also do `docker inspect <image id>` which will tell you the details about the `image`. If you just want to know the tag you can do

```
docker inspect --format='{{range .RepoTags}}{{.}}{{end}}' <image id>
```

A little example of formatting a history:

```
docker history --format "{{.ID}}" <IMAGE> | grep -v "<missing>" | xargs docker inspect --format='{{range .RepoTags}}{{.}}{{end}} {{range .ContainerConfig.Cmd}}{{.}}{{end}}'
```

Comment: Thanks - I'm more interested in being able to easily view each Dockerfile of everything the docker images I'm pulling depends on. As they say, the source code never lies...